# Soma usando MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteorjs

Estou desenvolvendo uma TaskList para entender como `MeteorJS` funciona.

Na aplicação o usuário pode inserir o nome da tarefa, quantas horas ele vai gastar nela e quando vai realiza-la.
O sistema devolve uma lista com todas as tarefas do usuário e a soma das horas das tarefas, eis o problema, como somar as horas das tarefas usando o `MeteorJS`?

Código para inserir a tarefa.

```
Template.new.events({
  "submit form" : function(e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var InputName = $("#taskName");
    var taskName = InputName.val();

    var InputTime = $("#taskTime");
    var taskTime = InputTime.val();

    var InputDate = $("#taskDate");
    var taskDate = InputDate.val();

    var item = {name: taskName, time: taskTime , date: taskDate };
    Task.insert(item);

    InputName.val();

  }
});
```

Código para listar as tarefas

```
Template.list.helpers({
  tasklist: function() {
    return Task.find({});
  }
});
```

Código da View

```
{{#each tasklist}}
  <tr>
    <td id="time">
      {{time}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{name}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{date}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn remove-btn  ">Remove</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}

<p class="text-center total " id="resultado">
  Total Hours:
</p>
```

Comment: Em qual formato você está inserindo a data/hora no banco de dados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o formato da hora for `Hora:Minuto`. **Exemplo**: `02:00 (Duas Horas)`.

Criando uma nova propriedade no `helpers` do template  `list` você pode retornar o total de horas, veja no exemplo abaixo como ficaria em seu código.

Helpers:

```
Template.list.helpers({
  tasklist: function() {
    return Task.find({});
  },
  // Propriedade que retorna o total de horas.
  totalHoras: function() {
    var hora = 0;
    var min = 0;

    Task.find().map(function(doc) {
      var horaMinuto = doc.data.split(':'); // Aqui suponho que sua data seja, por exemplo, '02:00' (Duas Horas).
      hora += parseInt(horaMinuto[0]);
      min += parseInt(horaMinuto[1]);
      if(min >= 60) {
        min -= 60;
        hora += 1;
      }
    });

    return ('00' + hora).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + min).slice(-2);
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="list">
  <p class="text-center total " id="resultado">
    Total Hours: {{totalHoras}}
  </p>
</template>
```

Fonte: [Lógica para calcular horas](https://computacaoemfoco.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/calculos-com-horas-em-javascript/).